# Displaying a list in a view from data passed from a controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm passing a list in JSON format from my controller, the data from the list is not being displayed in the view for some reason.

Here is the data being passed in controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetIndustryCat(string Country)
        { var dataContext = MvcApplication.GetDataContext();
            var Location = dataContext.Locations.Single(c => c.Location_Name == Country);
            var IndustryCat = dataContext.IndustryCategories.Where(c => c.Location_ID == Location.Location_ID).ToList();
            return Json(new {Cat = IndustryCat.Select(c => c.IndustryCategory_Name) });
        }
```

Here is the view:

```
</select>
<script>
    $("#selectindustrycat").hide();
    $("select")
        .change(function () {
            var str = "";
            $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "GetIndustryCat",
                type: "POST",
                data: { Country: str },
                success: function (data) {

                }
            }).done(function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("#selectindustrycat").append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
                }
                $("#selectindustrycat").show();
            });
    });


</script>
```

The selection option list displays but it has no data in it.

Comment: did you try alert(data) in done function? is it not null?

Comment: @HienNyugen when i do alert(data) it displays [object Object] but when i put it under for loop and type alert(data[i]) it doesnt displays anything.

Comment: can you show us your data alert here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change from data to data.Cat

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Cat.length; i++) {
                    $("#selectindustrycat").append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
                }
```